# Move ImageView To Center Of Screen in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-image, android-windowmanager

i m working in an application which have 2 imageview 1st one is left and onother is in right ...when page will loaded imageview move nd it goes to center of screen..
i.e

**imageview-------->center<----------imageview**

i m using translate animation to move the  images which take 4 parameter

i.e

```
 TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
```

but the problem is nothing is displayed ..

my XML File Is

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  
android:id="@+id/topRelativeLayout" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/centerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_header"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_footer" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_footer"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_header" />
</LinearLayout>  </RelativeLayout>
```

in My Applicationn On createview java code is

```
   DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;


    Log.d("Screen Width",String.valueOf(width));
    Log.d("Screen Height",String.valueOf(height));
    Log.d("Screen Half Width",String.valueOf(width/2));
    Log.d("Screen HalHeight",String.valueOf(height/2));

    header=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_header);
    moveImageToLeftToCenter(header,height,width);
    footer=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_footer);
    moveImageToRightToCenter( footer,height,width );
```

and the function code is

```
  public void moveImageToLeftToCenter(ImageView img, int height, int width ){

    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, width/2,height/2,height/2);// - originalPos[0] , 0, yDest - originalPos[1] );
    anim.setDuration(3000);
    anim.setFillAfter( true );
    img.startAnimation(anim);
    }

public void moveImageToRightToCenter(ImageView img,int height, int width ){

    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( width/2, 0,height/2,height/2);// - originalPos[0] , 0, yDest - originalPos[1] );
    anim.setDuration(3000);
    anim.setFillAfter( true );
    img.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

My Logcat values are

```
05-11 11:27:33.762: D/Screen Width(4090): 1152
05-11 11:27:33.762: D/Screen Height(4090): 672
05-11 11:27:33.762: D/Screen Half Width(4090): 576
05-11 11:27:33.762: D/Screen HalHeight(4090): 336
```

i cant understand what is the problem..if anyone know than help me....
thanks in advance friends

Comment: thew imageview is shown? but it does not move ?

Comment: can you try adding anim.setFillEnabled(true); after setFillAfter call.

Comment: Nope @N5.   imageview is also not displaying......

Comment: nope @denizt nothing happend

Comment: hv u chnage visibility in cide?

Comment: @Tufan can you also try moving your code piece to animate imageview into onWindowsFocusChanged function. It might help.(You can just override it via Eclipse helper.)

Comment: you mean to say something like this   @Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
  int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
  int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
  
  
  moveImageToLeftToCenter(header,height,width);
  moveImageToRightToCenter( footer,height,width );
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
 }

Comment: @Tufan yes i meant to say that.

Comment: dosent work bro....i had tried than post..............id display for a short period of tm but dosent move to center

Comment: nope bro @n5 ....now it is displaying but dosent move to center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also did something like that and i can manage to do it in onWindowsFocusChanged function. Code is below, I know that you already tried it but maybe you can find something useful from it.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation fadeIn = FadeIn(3000);
    fadeIn.setStartOffset(0);
    set.addAnimation(fadeIn);

    RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splashLayout);
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int statusBarOffset = dm.heightPixels - root.getMeasuredHeight();

    int originalPos[] = new int[2];
    splashImage.getLocationOnScreen(originalPos);

    int xDest = dm.widthPixels / 2;
    xDest -= (splashImage.getMeasuredWidth() / 2);
    int yDest = dm.heightPixels / 2 - (splashImage.getMeasuredHeight() / 2)
            - statusBarOffset;

    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, xDest
            - originalPos[0], 0, yDest - originalPos[1]);
    anim.setDuration(3000);
    set.addAnimation(anim);

    Animation fadeOut = FadeOut(1000);
    fadeOut.setStartOffset(3000);
    set.addAnimation(fadeOut);

    set.setFillAfter(true);
    set.setFillEnabled(true);
    splashImage.startAnimation(set);
}

private Animation FadeIn(int t) {
    Animation fade;
    fade = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    fade.setDuration(t);
    fade.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return fade;
}

private Animation FadeOut(int t) {
    Animation fade;
    fade = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.1f);
    fade.setDuration(t);
    fade.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return fade;
}
```

Here what I tried to do is, move splash image from a specific position to a bit lower, by applying animation set on the image. Here FadeIn, and FadeOut are just animations for changing the alpha of image, so you just need to supply your own animation to animation set.

Hope it will help you somehow.

Regards,

Comment: can you post also what is fadein and fadeout it says me method undefined

Comment: i add them into post @Tufan, you can check.

Comment: thx bro @denizt not atleast it is moving but can you tell me what should i chnage in my code so that it goes only to center

Comment: @Tufan, you first get the original position of your images like int originalPos[] = new int[2];
    splashImage.getLocationOnScreen(originalPos); and afterwards you move from that original position to width/2 - originalPos[0]. I did not try it, because i am not on my dev machine, but it should be goes like that.

Comment: okay it is fine that when i change acording to you it works..but the proble is  image is moving and goes to center but it goes to top of center ..her you can see   http://imgur.com/aZY0VIR

Comment: hmm, can you remove set.setFillEnabled(true) from the code. It might be the problem @Tufan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77489/discussion-between-denizt-and-tufan).

Comment: Nope Bro it is not the issue ..again same proble start with left center------>moving ------->slowly slowly goes up.... i m posting logcat woy will get idea     05-11 13:21:59.133: D/xDest(15315): 501
05-11 13:21:59.133: D/yDest(15315): 207
05-11 13:21:59.133: D/orisinialpos[0](15315): 0
05-11 13:21:59.133: D/originalPos[1](15315): 325
nd done somthing like this     TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( originalPos[0],xDest-originalPos[0], 0, yDest - originalPos[1]);

Comment: check this bro i have this issue now   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450295/move-image-to-the-center-of-the-screen-android

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, It worked for me

```
public void moveImageToRightToCenter(ImageView img ,int screenWidth)
    {
        img.setTranslationX(screenWidth);
        img.animate()
                .translationX(0)
                .setDuration(300)
                .setStartDelay(300);
    }
```

Comment: acording to you i had done some changes in my code but nthmg happend img.setTranslationX(width); img.animate() .translationX(width/2) .setDuration(300) .setStartDelay(300);