# Translate Animation to the center of the screen Android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, animation

I have an image view on the screen and I want to make an animation to move it to the center of that screen. I just don't know how to calculate or get that center. The image is not on top/bottom/left/right.

Thank you!

Comment: Pasting the section of your code that handles this will help others know what assistance to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Using pivotX 50% and pivotY 50% it will scale to center:

```
   <scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.2"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.2"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="175"/>
```

Comment: Yes but I want to make a translate animation, not a scale

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160656/move-imageview-to-center-of-screen-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that would help you.

```
void moveToCenterAnimation(Context context, View view, long duration) {

    //Get position on screen
    int[] pos = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(pos);

    //Get screen size
    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    screenWidth = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    screenHeight = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

    //x and y translate animators
    ObjectAnimator xAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", screenWidth/2f - pos[0] + view.getWidth()/2f);
    ObjectAnimator yAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", screenHeight/2f - pos[1] + view.getHeight()/2f);
    xAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    yAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    
    //Play animator
    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorSet.playTogether(xAnimator, yAnimator);
    animatorSet.start();
}

//Then use this function to animate view
moveToCenterAnimation(getContext(), yourImageView, 300);
```

Comment: Can you explain what that int[] pos = int[2] does?

Comment: @Alexandru Can you show me xml, and java codes you've written?

Comment: Hmm, In the end just wasted time